# Is there a way to specify a default eslint configuration file when using ALE plugin of Vim?

Tags: plugin-ale

I'm using [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) for linting my programming code, and I have following configuration part to specify lint tool for JavaScript.

```
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}

let g:ale_fixers = {
\   'javascript': ['eslint'],
\}
```

It works pretty well if eslint could find there is a `.eslintrc` or `.eslintrc.json` under current project directory. However I wonder what if I just want to use Vim to edit an arbitrary JavaScript file, it will pop up a lint error message which says `aslant configuration error` due to lack of the eslint configuration file.

So I wonder if there is a way to specify a default lint configuration file if there is no eslint configuration file could be found under current project folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the eslint [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats) we can read

> **Note**: If you have a personal configuration file in your home directory (`~/.eslintrc`), it will only be used if no other configuration files are found. Since a personal configuration would apply to everything inside of a user’s directory, including third-party code, this could cause problems when running ESLint.
>
> By default, ESLint will look for configuration files in all parent folders up to the root directory. This can be useful if you want all of your projects to follow a certain convention, but can sometimes lead to unexpected results. To limit ESLint to a specific project, place `"root": true` inside the `eslintConfig` field of the `package.json` file or in the `.eslintrc.*` file at your project’s root level. ESLint will stop looking in parent folders once it finds a configuration with `"root": true`.

So I didn't test it but you should be able to put a `.eslintrc` file in your home directory to create a default configuration.